# TLI file throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, com, c++-cli

I am using COM component in C++/CLI, one of the method of COM, takes 'void *' as parameter. My code compiles fine but throws 'System.Accessviolation' exception at runtime
following is the code snippet. What could be reason for this exception.

```
// C++ managed Code
void ManagedWrapper::InitializeConfig(ManagedConfigruation  ^objConfiguration)
{    
    objConfiguration->SetConfigurationValue();
         IntPtr p = objConfiguration->GetObjectPtr();
    m_objCameraConfig->InitializeNetworkConfig(p.ToPointer());

} 

//COM signature for InitializeNetworkConfig in IDL file
[helpstring("method InitializeCameraConfig")] HRESULT InitializeNetworkConfig([in] void *configparam);
```

Answer (score 0):

How old is the COM object and do it need administrator priviliges? I know that some core functionality got the UAC leash on them when Windows moved from XP to Vista and 7.
It maybe totally wrong but hopefully that gives you a pointer in the right direction...