# Passing Unmanaged object reference to Unmanaged method in C++/CLI managed method

Tags: c#, c++-cli, interop, com-interop, unmanaged

I am getting exception when i am trying to pass unmanaged object, to COM method in method written in managed C++/CLI class. Following is the code sample

```
//C++/CLI class 
public ref class PSIAAdaptorManagedWrapper
{
    CConfiguration *Configuration;
    void InitializeConfig();    
}

//C++/CLI Method implementation 
void PSIAAdaptorManagedWrapper::InitializeConfig() {
    Configuration = new CConfiguration();
    Configuration->IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    Configuration->UserName = "User";
    Configuration->password = "password";    
    SomeComObject->GetInitiConfig((void *) Configuration);  // Exception line
}

//signature of COM object from IDL file (observer paramer it takes is in) 
[helpstring("method InitializeCameraConfig")]
HRESULT GetInitiConfig([in] void *configparam);
```

Above code compiles fine. But when execute I get "System.AccessViolation" runt time error on line. I think it is because, I am trying to allocate unmanaged memory in managed function. But I am not sure how to get around this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++/CLI : COM interop , TLI file throwing exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298649/c-cli-com-interop-tli-file-throwing-exception)

Comment: Possibly similary but here I have issue regarding  passing unmanaged object to COM method in managed method. Post if you have any link that will help

Comment: You have to do the marshaling before passing the anmanaged code to a managed function. You should check these links below. [SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608876/c-sharp-dllimport-with-c-boolean-function-not-returning-correctly/4621621#4621621) [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx) [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/unmanaged_to_managed.aspx)

Comment: Btw, you have a memory leak unless you use a tracking pointer here: `CConfiguration^  Configuration;` and `Configuration = gcnew CConfiguration();`

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that a user name or password are incorrect. AccessViolation is best noted for those issues.
Also, I dont see why anything should go wrong the way you are handling things in your code above.